# Refrigerator with humidity control

Tags: refrigerator, storage

I just moved into a house which has a fridge that has humidity control on a couple of it's doors. The scale simply reads "low" to "high".

So, aside from the question of how this fridge is actually responding to the scale (I suspect it is not doing much), does anyone know what to store at "low" humidity and what to store at "high" humidity?

My instinct would basically be to store everything at low humidity - low moisture, low change of spoilage - but obviously I am missing something.

Comment: Apparently good wine with real corks should be kept in a high humidity fridge (or at least that's what my drinks fridge says). Some foods dry out in fridges (I think maybe cheese) but shouldn't be tightly wrapped either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leafy veggies such as lettuce and arugula should be kept in the high humidity drawer so they don't wilt.  Some peas and beans also.

Fruits generally go in the low humidity drawer as they can emit a gas that causes other fruits and veggies to rot faster.   Strawberries are susceptible to this gas and should be kept in high humidity.

I'd recommend a Google search for an exact list but I always just did V-High and F-Low for veggies and fruits respectively.

Comment: What about culinary vegetables that are botanical fruit (like tomatoes)?

Comment: http://msue.anr.msu.edu/news/refrigerator_humidity_effects_on_produce_quality